# How to make a function visible through a header file in C

Tags: c, interface, header, function-prototypes, c-header

I have several header files in a library: `header1.h`, `header2.h`...
I also have a general header file for the library: `mylib.h`

I want the user to import the `main.h` file and get access to **only some of the functions** in the other header files.

For example, in the library:

```
// header1.h
void a(void);
void b(void);
```

-

```
// mylib.h

// I can't use this:
#include "header1.h"
// because it would make b function visible.

// Link to function a ????????
```

And in my main program:

```
// main.c
#include "mylib.h"

int main(void) {

    a(); // Visible: no problem
    b(); // Not visible: error

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate function prototypes into different headers, depending on whether they should be "visible"<sup>*1</sup> or not (but be "internal").

- `header1_internal.h`
- `header1.h`
- `header2_internal.h`
- `header2.h`
- ...

Include into the `*_internal.h` headers the related `*.h` header.

Include the `*_internal.h` headers into your lib's related modules.

Do not include any `*_internal.h` into `mylib.h`.

---

<sup>*1: Please note that even when not providing a prototype this way the user might very well craft his/her own prototype and then link the function from `mylib`. So the functions not prototyped aren't unaccessible.</sup>

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having so many header files but I think this is the only solution we can find in C. Thank you.

Comment: @Octan: You are welcome. Please see my additional footnote.

Answer (score 0):

If `void b(void)` is not needed by other header file, and you have access to the source file, what about moving the declaration into the source file?

```
// header1.h
void a(void);
//void b(void);

// header1.c
/* some #include here */
void b(void);
/* other code here */
void b(void) {
    /* implement it */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Header files only contains functions that should be accessible by user of header. They represent public interface.

Watch this first:
[Organizing code into multiple files 1](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/106104128/53)
YouTube link: [Organizing code into multiple files 1](https://youtu.be/mnPbAtFhjgk)

[Organizing code into multiple files 2](http://nptel.ac.in/courses/106104128/54)
youTube link: [Organizing code into multiple files 2](https://youtu.be/wOvVQXYuBvk)

Additionally you can refer [Introduction To GCC by Brian Gough](https://tfetimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/An_Introduction_to_GCC-Brian_Gough.pdf) to get more insights into compilation and linking process using gcc.

Comment: Above mentioned videos contains everything you should know to use header files successfully.